# Download data in Excel using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, download

I'm Working with Asp Dot Net Mvc3 i want to download Excel file.Following is My Controller,

```
public ActionResult DownloadTRUnutilizedOwnershipInvoke(string strGeo, string strVertical, int intMonth, int intFlag,string strType)
{
     TRUnutilizedOwnershipModel objTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel = new TRUnutilizedOwnershipModel();
     objTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel = objTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.GetUnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities(strGeo, strVertical, intMonth, intFlag,strType);
     objTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.ExportUnutilizedOwnership("UnutilizedOwnership", objTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.lstunutilizedownershipExcelentities);                                           
}
```

Following is my Model,

```
       public void ExportUnutilizedOwnership<T>(string fileName, List<T> lstdata)
    {
        try
        {
            Table tableData = new Table();                                               HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();                
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName + ".xls"));.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";= "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                                    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(UnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities))
                    {
                        List<UnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities> lstNewdata = (List<UnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities>)(object)lstdata;
                        tableData = TableUnutilizedOwnershipExcelData(lstNewdata);
                    }                                                                                            tableData.RenderControl(htw);                                       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

          public Table TableUnutilizedOwnershipExcelData(List<UnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities> lstUnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities)
    {
        try
        {
            Table tableData = new Table();
            TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow();
            TableHeaderCell hCurrentOwnership = new TableHeaderCell();
            TableHeaderCell hCount = new TableHeaderCell();

            hCurrentOwnership.Text = "CurrentOwnership";
            hCount.Text = "Count";

            rowHeader.Cells.Add(hCurrentOwnership);
            rowHeader.Cells.Add(hCount);

            rowHeader.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            ApplyStyle(rowHeader);
            tableData.Rows.Add(rowHeader);
            foreach (UnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities excelEntity in lstUnutilizedOwnershipExcelEntities)
            {
                TableRow rowData = new TableRow();

                TableCell cellCurrentOwnership = new TableCell();
                TableCell cellCount = new TableCell();

                cellCurrentOwnership.Text = excelEntity.CurrentOwnership;
                cellCount.Text = Convert.ToString(excelEntity.cnt);

                rowData.Cells.Add(cellCurrentOwnership);
                rowData.Cells.Add(cellCount);

                tableData.Rows.Add(rowData);
                ApplyStyle(rowData);
            }
            return tableData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void ApplyStyle(TableRow row)
    {
        try
        {
            row.BorderColor = Color.FromName("#CCCCCC");
            row.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);
            row.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I couldn't Get the Popup window for Download Excel.whether i missed anything in this code to get the Popup for Download Excel Popup

Comment: just to mention that you are not creating an excel file, you are forging headers to trick browser to open html table with excel. It's just matter of time or new excel version when this approach will totaly fail. For now AFAIK Excel 2007+ warns user that content is not excel file. And strog advice is to move to some excel library and produce real excel file, it's pretty easy with EEPlus and similar libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ActionMethods(ActionModel model)
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    string contentType = "application/xlx";
                    string fileExtension = ".xlsx";


                    DataTable dt = //Set your data which is reflect on excel

                    ExcelExport.SaveToExcelFile(dt, strFilePath);

                  return File(strFilePath, contentType, "Reports" + fileExtension);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Action");
            }

   public static void SaveToExcelFile(System.Data.DataTable dt, string filename)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            try
            {
                Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
                Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];


                Style ColumnStyle = wb.Styles.Add("Style1", Type.Missing);
                ColumnStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                ColumnStyle.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;


                // export column headers
                for (int colNdx = 0; colNdx < dt.Columns.Count; colNdx++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[1, colNdx + 1] = dt.Columns[colNdx].ColumnName;
                    Range exrange = (ws.Cells[1, colNdx + 1]) as Range;
                    exrange.Style = ColumnStyle;
                }

                // export data
                for (int rowNdx = 0; rowNdx < dt.Rows.Count; rowNdx++)
                {
                    for (int colNdx = 0; colNdx < dt.Columns.Count; colNdx++)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[rowNdx + 2, colNdx + 1] = dt.Rows[rowNdx][colNdx];
                    }
                }
                wb.SaveAs(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            finally
            {
                app.Quit();
            }

        }
```